# How to single step through #define statements using gdb

Tags: gcc, gdb

I am using gcc compiler. I am working on a code that frequently involves writing chunks of statements inside a single #define directive. For example the following :

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#define DO_RR(x) do { \
for(i=0;i<x; i++) \
    printf("%d", i); \
}while(0);

int main() {
  int i=0;
  DO_RR(5)
  return 0;
}
```

Now I want to be able to single step through the statements in DO_RR. However when I try it, the control jumps directly from DO_RR statement in main to the next statement and does not single step. Is there anyway to achieve stepping inside the preprocessor blocks ?

Comment: @OP: to format as code, just paste, select and hit Ctrl-K (indents by 4 spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, #defines are expanded by the preprocessor and are not present in the code.

Comment: Simple as that, and one of the best reasons not to use #define, but to use inline functions instead. It should be changed to `inline void do_rr(int x) { for(int i=0;i<x; i++) printf("%d", i); }`

Comment: @tenfour using inline is an excellent idea. However, for me it defeats the purpose of using #define (not evident from the example).

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @Angelom's answer, you can *workaround* this by using functions. Move whatever code you can from the `#define` into a function, and you will be able to step through the function call.

Ideally, and most often, you can replace the entire `#define` with an inline function.